# What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a graph to be a Hamiltonian Chordal Graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path, chordal-graphs

**Chordal Graph.**

A chordal graph is one in which all cycles of four or more vertices have a chord, which is an edge that is not part of the cycle but connects two vertices of the cycle.

**Hamiltonian Graph.**

If there exists a closed walk in the connected graph that visits every vertex of the graph exactly once (except starting vertex) without repeating the edges, then such a graph is called as a Hamiltonian graph.

Based on these definitions, I suppose the following definition of Hamiltonian Chordal graph.

**Hamiltonian Chordal Graph.**

A graph that satisfies all the properties of  Hamiltonian graph and Chordal graph.

**Note.**

The graph under consideration are simple and undirected.

Comment: The Hamiltonian path problem is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete for chordal graphs, so it is unlikely there is a nicer characterization than saying that the graph must be both chordal and Hamiltonian.